# Unable to learn third relentless force

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been busy with other quests and have not talked with Wulfgar, but the guests say that he has to teach me the third Relentless Force word.

I went to High Hrothgar and saw that ancient writing in fire in front of Wulfgar on the floor and that there was a marker pointing to that and one marker pointing to Angeir.

However, when I go over to Angeir first, he says Wulfgar must ***first*** teach the third Relentless Force word, so I go over to the marker in front of Wulfgar, but it does nothing... I try to talk with him and he still does nothing. What am I actually supposed to do here?

Comment: Please, edit your question in a more readable way.

Answer (score -1):

I searched across internet, and found some similiar problems. Here are the main suggestions:

- Staring at the word and at wulfgar;
- You get the horn in Riverwood from Dalphen because she took it. She leaves a note where the horn would be. Only after you go to Riverwood and get the horn.
- Don't talk to him. Just step away from him and wait for him to Shout. Alternatively, load that autosave from when you entered the building.

Here are the links, for reference:

https://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/615804-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/answers/307725-how-do-you-get-past-the-master-wulfgar-glitch

https://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/615804-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/answers/301163-the-horn-of-jurgen-windcaller-wulfgar-glitch

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615805-/61003281

Try these, might work for you.

Good luck!

(Thanks for teaching me about details on answer. Still learning =D )

Comment: Explain what the relevant parts from each of these links are, since links don't always live forever.